# Load data from database with gui c# and use SqlDataReader.ExecuteReader() twice

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, connection

I am very new to C# and coding, so I hope you will be patient with me. :)

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I built my  database connection and it worked. I will post my code tomorrow, but here my first example:

```
sSQL = "select person_id from person where person_email_adress = "+ email;
cmd.CommandText = sSQL
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(dr.Read()){
   person_id = dr.GetString(0)
}
```

This worked fine, but my problem is in the second SQL command:

```
sSQL = "select article from purchase where person_id = "+ person_id;
cmd.CommandText = sSQL
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(dr.Read()){
   // random stuff
}
```

My problem is, that my second `SqlDataReader` returns no rows, but if I run the same query in SQLDeveloper with the same `person_id`, I have more then 10 hits.

I know that the `dr.Read()` is empty, because I make the following thing:

```
if(!dr.HasRow) {
    MessageBox.text("This query is empty");
} else {
    MessageBox.text("This query got some hit");
}
```

I want to go in the while, and read the lines, but I always get the problem, that `dr` is empty.

I also checked if the SQL output is right with a `MessageBox` and it was right.

What now?

I hope you understand my bad English and if you have any question I am at your service. :)

Thanks and regards,

Xplosio

Comment: Have you run it line-by-line in the debugger to make sure that `person_id` has the value you expect?

Comment: yes it gives me the value I expect (10369)

Comment: You should close the OracleDataReader after you read it: `dr.Close();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would debug line-by-line to make sure that `person_id` has the value you expect.

Second, I would change *both* queries to use parameters:

```
sSQL = "select article from purchase where person_id = :person_id";
cmd.CommandText = sSQL
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("person_id", person_id))
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(dr.Read()){

   // random stuff

}
```

Comment: ah this is how you use parameter in c#. Thank you :) I only know it in java with a questionmark, but I don't think it will help me because my problem is, that I get the right parameter (I checked it many times, because I thought also, that the person_id is wrong, but its not)

Comment: So if the query is right and the parameter value is right - the only possible cause is you are querying a different database.

Comment: Oh my god.... you are right... I made an access to the wrong database. Thanks a lot and sorry

Comment: No worries - sometimes it takes a second set of eyes to see the problem.  Glad you figured it out.